# What's the easiest way to generate a PE32+ executable?

Tags: cross-platform, portable-executable

I'm currently working on a library that reads PE32/PE32+ binaries, and I need to generate a sample PE32+ binary so that I can read the headers as part of the library tests. Assuming a simple "Hello World" application, what's the simplest way to create both a PE32/PE32+ binary executable using the same source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to create a "Win32 console application" empty project with Visual Studio, add "64-bit" configuration and compile both 32-bit and 64-bit executables. This will require 64-bit Visual C++ compiler installed in Visual Studio which is present starting with Visual Studio 2005 but is not installed by default.